# Google Admob AD can't be displayed in Fragment of Android

Tags: android, admob

I created an Admob AD, it can display correctly in my other layout, now I create a Tabbed Activity, and place the AD in Fragment, but the AD can't be displayed, why?

Thanks!

**PlaceholderFragmentOld.java**

```
package ui.tab;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import bll.PublicParFun;
import info.dodata.messagecleanup.R;

public class PlaceholderFragmentOld extends Fragment {

    private AdView adView;

    public PlaceholderFragmentOld() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cleanup_delete_fragment_old, container, false);

        adView=(AdView)(rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView));
        SetAD(adView);

         return rootView;
    }

     public  void SetAD(AdView adView) {
        if (PublicParFun.IsRegistered == false) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }else{
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

**CleanupDelete.java**

```
package ui;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import info.dodata.messagecleanup.R;
import ui.tab.PlaceholderFragmentOld;
import ui.tab.PlaceholderFragmentPerson;
import ui.tab.PlaceholderFragmentReduce;
import ui.tab.PlaceholderFragmentTrim;

public class CleanupDelete extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cleanup_delete);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentOld();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentReduce();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentTrim();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentPerson();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid section number");
            }

            return fragment;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {           
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

**cleanup_delete.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

**cleanup_delete_fragment_old.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tVDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            style="@style/myTextDesciption"
            android:text="This is a descript"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutToolBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="4" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/BtnClose" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logs**

```
06-17 05:41:46.257    1098-1098/? I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
06-17 05:41:46.287        37-90/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-17 05:41:46.297    1098-1098/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-17 05:41:50.757      280-660/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=info.dodata.messagecleanup/ui.CleanupDelete} from pid 1098
06-17 05:41:50.857      280-660/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 594K, 23% free 7250K/9408K, paused 59ms, total 62ms
06-17 05:41:51.087    1098-1098/? W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
06-17 05:41:51.097    1098-1098/? I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
06-17 05:41:51.107    1098-1098/? I/Ads﹕ Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
06-17 05:41:51.127    1098-1158/? I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
06-17 05:41:51.227        37-37/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-17 05:41:51.237    1098-1098/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-17 05:41:51.457      280-296/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed info.dodata.messagecleanup/ui.CleanupDelete: +583ms
06-17 05:41:52.147    1098-1098/? W/Ads﹕ JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=61e3264c-f1ab-4489-9c5e-d763d24c6644&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D12627135929191627212%26seq_num%3D5%26rm%3D2%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7327000.7327000.0%26hl%3Den%26smart_w%3Dfull%26submodel%3Dsdk%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26platform%3Dunknown%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms%3DyofcUh5kzK8yMrXnioUeFWtyWysBoIEvca6BjhVTC3YftHYI-sUYHHFAzrB4YMjahBQWhHCE8cYlTO9UsYiB0fmKUzlBD2w5RhzwdUa9nxO2uInhwWgLcUexanJtcmGuHI1cfsuqoWNUHIVmQizMEFKdR4UiKl9WaHsf_3BEEbFsPfrJDO9ie9fXI7pCYgJ5zASx_DB_qFaOmjKUbiT2drQWD-KHGrreX67IHb2l5owfcJz2esVF55MwjqYgI5sSgvp8AWtBNC2qB7EVexlvD6bmmnMp9f0IhD8fyBahMCu5FWDcIjYt43B8MFOQjCWnIaD9qwUNVm4oJ6Vx6PWigg%26format%3D320x50_as%26smart_h%3Dauto%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26request_id%3D61e3264c-f1ab-4489-9c5e-d763d24c6644%26am%3D0%26cap%3Dm%26u_w%3D320%26u_h%3D533%26msid%3Dinfo.dodata.messagecleanup%26app_name%3D3.android.info.dodata.messagecleanup%26an%3D3.android.info.dodata.messagecleanup%26net%3Ded%26u_audio%3D4%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D4%26support_transparent_background%3Dfalse%26pimp%3D4%26currts%3D656976%26basets%3D458533%26pclick%3D0%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.5%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dtrue%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D0%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26askip%3D4%26gsb%3D3g%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_av_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dtrue%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26eid%3D46621099%26tcar%3D36%26jsv%3D171%26urll%3D1276&base_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1434519712134.
    (null:1)
06-17 05:41:52.147    1098-1098/? W/Web Console﹕ The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=61e3264c-f1ab-4489-9c5e-d763d24c6644&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D12627135929191627212%26seq_num%3D5%26rm%3D2%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7327000.7327000.0%26hl%3Den%26smart_w%3Dfull%26submodel%3Dsdk%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26platform%3Dunknown%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms%3DyofcUh5kzK8yMrXnioUeFWtyWysBoIEvca6BjhVTC3YftHYI-sUYHHFAzrB4YMjahBQWhHCE8cYlTO9UsYiB0fmKUzlBD2w5RhzwdUa9nxO2uInhwWgLcUexanJtcmGuHI1cfsuqoWNUHIVmQizMEFKdR4UiKl9WaHsf_3BEEbFsPfrJDO9ie9fXI7pCYgJ5zASx_DB_qFaOmjKUbiT2drQWD-KHGrreX67IHb2l5owfcJz2esVF55MwjqYgI5sSgvp8AWtBNC2qB7EVexlvD6bmmnMp9f0IhD8fyBahMCu5FWDcIjYt43B8MFOQjCWnIaD9qwUNVm4oJ6Vx6PWigg%26format%3D320x50_as%26smart_h%3Dauto%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26request_id%3D61e3264c-f1ab-4489-9c5e-d763d24c6644%26am%3D0%26cap%3Dm%26u_w%3D320%26u_h%3D533%26msid%3Dinfo.dodata.messagecleanup%26app_name%3D3.android.info.dodata.messagecleanup%26an%3D3.android.info.dodata.messagecleanup%26net%3Ded%26u_audio%3D4%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D4%26support_transparent_background%3Dfalse%26pimp%3D4%26currts%3D656976%26basets%3D458533%26pclick%3D0%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.5%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dtrue%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D0%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26askip%3D4%26gsb%3D3g%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_av_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dtrue%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26eid%3D46621099%26tcar%3D36%26jsv%3D171%26urll%3D1276&base_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1434519712134.
            at null:1
06-17 05:41:52.207    1098-1098/? W/Ads﹕ JS: The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=61e3264c-f1ab-4489-9c5e-d763d24c6644&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D12627135929191627212%26seq_num%3D5%26rm%3D2%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7327000.7327000.0%26hl%3Den%26smart_w%3Dfull%26submodel%3Dsdk%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26platform%3Dunknown%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms%3DyofcUh5kzK8yMrXnioUeFWtyWysBoIEvca6BjhVTC3YftHYI-sUYHHFAzrB4YMjahBQWhHCE8cYlTO9UsYiB0fmKUzlBD2w5RhzwdUa9nxO2uInhwWgLcUexanJtcmGuHI1cfsuqoWNUHIVmQizMEFKdR4UiKl9WaHsf_3BEEbFsPfrJDO9ie9fXI7pCYgJ5zASx_DB_qFaOmjKUbiT2drQWD-KHGrreX67IHb2l5owfcJz2esVF55MwjqYgI5sSgvp8AWtBNC2qB7EVexlvD6bmmnMp9f0IhD8fyBahMCu5FWDcIjYt43B8MFOQjCWnIaD9qwUNVm4oJ6Vx6PWigg%26format%3D320x50_as%26smart_h%3Dauto%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26request_id%3D61e3264c-f1ab-4489-9c5e-d763d24c6644%26am%3D0%26cap%3Dm%26u_w%3D320%26u_h%3D533%26msid%3Dinfo.dodata.messagecleanup%26app_name%3D3.android.info.dodata.messagecleanup%26an%3D3.android.info.dodata.messagecleanup%26net%3Ded%26u_audio%3D4%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D4%26support_transparent_background%3Dfalse%26pimp%3D4%26currts%3D656976%26basets%3D458533%26pclick%3D0%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.5%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dtrue%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D0%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26askip%3D4%26gsb%3D3g%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_av_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dtrue%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26eid%3D46621099%26tcar%3D36%26jsv%3D171%26urll%3D1276&base_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1434519712134.
    (null:1)
06-17 05:41:52.207    1098-1098/? W/Web Console﹕ The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_id=61e3264c-f1ab-4489-9c5e-d763d24c6644&request_scenario=online_request&type=admob&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fgma%3Fsession_id%3D12627135929191627212%26seq_num%3D5%26rm%3D2%26fdz%3D-1%26adtest%3Don%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v7327000.7327000.0%26hl%3Den%26smart_w%3Dfull%26submodel%3Dsdk%26gnt%3D3%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310260%26platform%3Dunknown%26u_sd%3D1.5%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D0%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D5%26ms%3DyofcUh5kzK8yMrXnioUeFWtyWysBoIEvca6BjhVTC3YftHYI-sUYHHFAzrB4YMjahBQWhHCE8cYlTO9UsYiB0fmKUzlBD2w5RhzwdUa9nxO2uInhwWgLcUexanJtcmGuHI1cfsuqoWNUHIVmQizMEFKdR4UiKl9WaHsf_3BEEbFsPfrJDO9ie9fXI7pCYgJ5zASx_DB_qFaOmjKUbiT2drQWD-KHGrreX67IHb2l5owfcJz2esVF55MwjqYgI5sSgvp8AWtBNC2qB7EVexlvD6bmmnMp9f0IhD8fyBahMCu5FWDcIjYt43B8MFOQjCWnIaD9qwUNVm4oJ6Vx6PWigg%26format%3D320x50_as%26smart_h%3Dauto%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26request_id%3D61e3264c-f1ab-4489-9c5e-d763d24c6644%26am%3D0%26cap%3Dm%26u_w%3D320%26u_h%3D533%26msid%3Dinfo.dodata.messagecleanup%26app_name%3D3.android.info.dodata.messagecleanup%26an%3D3.android.info.dodata.messagecleanup%26net%3Ded%26u_audio%3D4%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D4%26support_transparent_background%3Dfalse%26pimp%3D4%26currts%3D656976%26basets%3D458533%26pclick%3D0%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.5%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dtrue%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D0%26client_sdk%3D1%26ex%3D1%26client%3Dca-app-pub-3940256099942544%26slotname%3D6300978111%26askip%3D4%26gsb%3D3g%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_th_autoplay_mediation_av_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26_efs%3Dtrue%26blockAutoClicks%3D0%26forceGmsDoritos%3D1%26eid%3D46621099%26tcar%3D36%26jsv%3D171%26urll%3D1276&base_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fmads%2Fgma&use_webview_loadurl=0&enable_auto_click_protection=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1434519712134.
            at null:1
06-17 05:41:52.247    1098-1102/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 403K, 11% free 4509K/5032K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 81ms
06-17 05:41:52.287    1098-1098/? W/Ads﹕ JS: The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
    (null:1)
06-17 05:41:52.287    1098-1098/? W/Web Console﹕ The page at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html displayed insecure content from file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png.
            at null:1
06-17 05:41:52.737    1098-1098/? W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 300x276 dp.
06-17 05:41:52.737    1098-1098/? W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 300x276 dp.
06-17 05:41:52.747    1098-1098/? D/webviewglue﹕ nativeDestroy view: 0x2a54fa50
06-17 05:41:53.077    1098-1098/? I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
06-17 05:41:53.107    1098-1098/? I/Ads﹕ Ad finished loading.
06-17 05:42:01.367    1098-1098/? I/Ads﹕ Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
06-17 05:42:01.367    1098-1098/? I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
06-17 05:42:05.997    1098-1102/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 631K, 15% free 4480K/5232K, paused 13ms+7ms, total 51ms
06-17 05:42:22.720      605-724/? D/ExchangeService﹕ Received deviceId from Email app: null
06-17 05:42:22.720      605-724/? D/ExchangeService﹕ !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
06-17 05:42:27.737      605-641/? D/ExchangeService﹕ !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
06-17 05:42:27.737      605-605/? D/ExchangeService﹕ !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
06-17 05:42:27.737      280-280/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-17 05:42:27.747      605-620/? D/ExchangeService﹕ !!! Email application not found; stopping self
06-17 05:42:27.747      280-419/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-17 05:42:27.757      605-605/? D/ExchangeService﹕ !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
06-17 05:42:27.767      605-605/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfefa8 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfefa8 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
            at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
            at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
            at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-17 05:42:27.767      605-605/? E/StrictMode﹕ null
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfefa8 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
            at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
            at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
            at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-17 05:42:27.777      280-491/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4103dd90
06-17 05:42:27.797      605-605/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff350 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff350 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
            at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
            at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
            at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
            at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-17 05:42:27.817      605-605/? E/StrictMode﹕ null
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cff350 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
            at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
            at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
            at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
            at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
            at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-17 05:42:27.817      605-607/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 433K, 20% free 2460K/3044K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 42ms
06-17 05:42:27.827      280-280/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f89e08
06-17 05:42:28.807    1098-1102/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 612K, 15% free 4465K/5220K, paused 4ms+8ms, total 52ms
06-17 05:42:40.848      280-376/? E/ThrottleService﹕ problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-17 05:42:49.697    1098-1102/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 561K, 15% free 4479K/5220K, paused 7ms+8ms, total 52ms
```

Comment: It's Ok after I remove   android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"

Comment: So we you can delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ViewPager just use  one necessary pieces of Admob code  for  xml and  java code  on the parent of that fragments .. You dont need to use on seperate fragments which is more problematic according to my personal experiences. Just use one on the parent